# How would I animate multiple views at the same time over different points?

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm quite new to Android Studio, and I would like to animate multiple images at the same time, over multiple coordinates.

Let's say I would like to move image A from 0/0 to 100/100, and then to 200/200; at the same time (eg. by the click of a button), image B shall be moved from 0/100 to 100/100, and then to 200/100. All with simple translations.

(As a plus, I would like to be able to set the duration of the movements independently.)

When the animations have finished, there should be an event (somthing like OnAnimationFinish?) to trigger other things, like enabling the start button again.

What would be the most effective way to do this? I know there is an AnimationSet in Android to store multiple animations, but I don't know if this is helpful here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` with `AnimatorSet` to play multiple animations simultaneously with proper listeners.

For example():

```
val imageXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX", translateX)
val imageYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationY", translateY)
val imageAlphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", if (reverse) 0F else 1F)

val animationSet = AnimatorSet()
        animationSet.playTogether(
                imageXAnimator,
                imageYAnimator,
                imageAlphaAnimator)
        animationSet.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        animationSet.duration = 1000
        animationSet.addListener(
            onStart = {
                //When animation is started
            },
            onEnd = {
                //When animation finishes
            }
        )
        animationSet.start()
```

Or a simple extension in `kotlin` which can be called on a specific `View`:

```
inline fun View.animateTranslationY(translationY: Float, duration: Long = 1000, startDelay: Long = 0) {
    val translationYAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "translationY", translationY)
    translationYAnimator.duration = duration
    translationYAnimator.startDelay = startDelay
    translationYAnimator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    translationYAnimator.addAnimatorListener(
            onStart = { },
            onEnd = { }
    )
    translationYAnimator.start()
}
```

Comment: I think this is the direction I'm looking for, thanks. Is it possible to chain multiple animations with an AnimatorSet, so that I would be able to play the animations over 3 points, like in the initial example? I guess that would be something like using an AnimationSet inside an AnimatorSet.

Comment: Yes you can use `AnimatorSet()` within an `AnimatorSet()` in its `playTogether()` method. But what you can do is create three different `AnimatorSets` and call other AnimatorSet in the `addAnimatorListener` in it `onEnd` method(or button click that's up to you). That should do the work for you.

Comment: @Cord if this solution worked for you then please mark this as the answer and upvote it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "View.animate()" method that allow you to access to its sub-methods and events to manage all these stuff. You just have to call "animate()" on a View (TextView, ImageView, EditBox, etc..) and then call its sub-methods to decide what kind of animation to perform: motion, rotation, changing transparency, etc... For each animation you can set a listener that will be called at Start and/or at the End of animation.

Answer (score 0):

Consider these two methods for both views

```
    private void animateFirstView(final ImageView first, long durationFirst, final long durationSecond) {
    first.setTranslationX(0);
    first.setTranslationY(0);
    first.animate().translationX(100).translationY(100).setDuration(durationFirst).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        first.animate().translationY(200).translationX(200).setDuration(durationSecond).setListener(null).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
}

private void animateSecondView(final ImageView second, long durationFirst, final long durationSecond) {
    second.setTranslationX(0);
    second.setTranslationY(100);
    second.animate().translationX(100).translationY(100).setDuration(durationFirst).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            second.animate().translationY(200).translationX(100).setDuration(durationSecond).setListener(null).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    }).setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can do this***:

```
private void playAnimation(final View view, final int endRangeY) { 
   view.animate().translationY(endRangeY) //endRangeY where you want to end the animation   
   .alpha(0.0f) 
   .setDuration(3000) 
   .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
     @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) { 
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);  
         }
     });
   }
```